# Is occult cognate with hell?

Tags: cognates

I have found a funny coincidence going through etymology. I found that the word occult comes from the same root *kel as hell. I feel like that is a spooky coincidence. The word *kel in PIE means to conceal, and the occult and hell are “concealed” in similar ways. Is this true?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=etymology+occult versus https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNT30D2sfV0-0LjyPTorBiuebHr0FQ%3A1575739227514&ei=W9_rXcL9Hsy_0PEPv4CQ4AI&q=etymology+hell&oq=etymology+hell&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l6j0i22i30l4.25147.25647..26202...0.4..0.111.341.3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i20i263.bSw9lk8BbIQ&ved=0ahUKEwiCl6iHhqTmAhXMHzQIHT8ABCwQ4dUDCAo&uact=5

Comment: @user6726: Fun fact about Google: because Google locates me in Germany, it presents the etymology of the German adjective *hell* "shiny, bright" here.

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed true!

Proto-Indo-European **ḱel* "conceal" > Proto-Germanic **haljō* "concealed place" > Old English *hell* "underworld" > English "hell"

Proto-Indo-European **ḱel* "conceal" > Latin **ob-celō* > *occulō* "conceal" > *occultus* "(that which is) concealed" > English "occult"

Comment: I thought so. Saw the same thing

Comment: The derivation of "hell" from *ḱel is widely, but not universally accepted. https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85636?rskey=uzK3oW&result=1#eid

Comment: @fdb That would make a good answer!

Comment: @Draconis you  misunderstand the purpose of the comment. *You* are supposed to bring that information into your post in order to improve it.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck No, I know, but I'm saying this question might benefit from another answer. Fdb could potentially provide much better information about the other viewpoint than I could, especially since I hadn't heard of this theory before and can't access the OED at the moment (though I have no doubt there's good information there).

Comment: A. Liberman's blog over at OUP agrees that there's no secure etymology. At any rate, *cognate* in the strict sense means a little bit more than having the same supposed root from an *arbitrary* point in time; allsomore if the lexicon isn't exclusively *monotonically branching*.

Comment: as for punishment, *detention hall* is a good comparison; for after-life, I wonder how *Val-Halla* compares (a place in the Netherlands, if I'm not mistaken); for a grim outlook: cp *hal* "salt", perhaps G *Halde* "mount", think Star-Wars' *salt mines*, cp G *Bau* "prison; mine; construction industry; building; ..."; cp for analogy *Saal* "hall", *Seil* "rope", \*sailaz, etc, cf *fesseln* "to tie sb. up", *fassen* "to hold"; also cp *Zeche* "mining business, mine", OHG "order" (cf Kroonen) vs biblical "bring ones *house* in order", and the whole *Arbeit, Erbe, orphan* thing; cp *Bergwerk*

Comment: I mean, cp *cell*, *cellarium*, *dungeons*, and eventually *Höhle* "cave", (cp *cave*, *cover*), *hollow*, *aushöhlen* "to make hollow" (cp \*(s)kel-, \*(s)ker-?), *hohlen* "to get, take, haul", though also cp *ceiling*, viz "roof", *ciel* "sky, heaven" as the basic symbol for protection. By the way, isn't *occult* rather close to *cult*, but also *occlude*? Eventually I punned *ox-cult*, cp the condemned Moloch Cult of Canaan.